# object is not taking full width in iphone

Tags: html, ios, iphone, cordova, video

I want to display youtube videos in iphone cordova app,

I tried `iframe` but it is not displaying some times.

So trying object tag

my code is

```
<div style="width: 100%; padding: 0" id="getWidth">

   <object width="100%" height="auto">
       <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/{{youtubeId}}">
           <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/{{youtubeId}}" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%;" height="auto">
    </object>
</div>
```

here `getWidth` is taking full screen but video is not showing in full width as shown in the following image

[image: left side safari inspect, right side iphone simulator]

**Note:** left side safari inspector and right side iphone simulator

Image is taken while trying to set width dynamically but in both cases result is same

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the [Youtube Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) for how to embed it in your application. Iframe is by far the best way to go.

Here is a sample html from the API

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```